# Find the middle term of $(1+x)^{2n}$ in its simplest form.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

> Find the middle term of $(1+x)^{2n}$ in its simplest form.

There are a total of $2n+1$ terms. The middle term is $\dfrac{2n+1}{2}$.

Hence $^{2n}C_{\frac{2n+1}{2}}x^{\frac{2n+1}{2}}$

But I feel I got the index of the middle term wrong. Also I'm not sure how to incorporate consideration of whether $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: $~\displaystyle \binom{2n}{n}x^n.$

Comment: $\frac {2n+1}2$ is not an integer.

Comment: The smallest degree term is $x^0$ and the largest degree term is $x^{2n}$ that does make $2n+1$ terms, but the middle term is the $x^n$ term.

Comment: So in $^nC_r$, $r$ must be an integer? Because I know $n$ doesn't have to be. Does $n$ being odd or even change $x^n$ being the middle term?

Comment: Why are you ignoring my first comment?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to be rude. I didn't realize you were somebody else. I also don't understand how to reach the answer you have kindly given me.

Comment: @ronald - if n isn't an integer you really shouldn't call it n. And then there is no middle term.

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson If there are $2n+1$ terms, then the middle term is the $(n+1)$th one.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for your response. How do you calculate or know/prove the middle term is $(n+1)$ if there are $2n+1$ terms in total? I can't visualize this in my head.

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson Well, there are $n$ terms before it and $n$ terms after it, so...

Answer (score 0):

In the sequence
$$\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\},$$
what is the middle term?  It's $3$.

Similarly, the binomial expansion $(1+x)^6$ is
$$1x^0 + 6x^1 + 15x^2 + 20x^3 +15x^4 + 6x^5 + 1x^6.$$
The middle term is $$20x^3.$$
What was the value of $n$ in the above example?  It was $3$, since $2(3) = 6$.  Do you now see how this works in the case of general $n$, and why the middle term of $(1+x)^{2n}$ has the form
$$Cx^n$$
for some coefficient $C$?

Comment: I see..so $2n+1$ is just the number of terms including $x^0$. But the middle term is still $\frac{2n}{2}=n$. Is it correct for me to get the middle term by dividing by $2$? Or is this just a coincidence and I shouldn't think of it this way?

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson It is the middle term of $2n+1$ terms starting at $0$ and ending with $2n$. The middle term is found as $\frac {0+2n}2=n$ (adding the first and last terms and dividing by $2$ in the usual way). You just have to apply the usual formula, but notice you are starting at $0$ not $1$. If you started at $1$ you would get $\frac {(2n+1)+1}2=n+1$ which is still an integer as expected for the middle term of an odd number of consecutive integers.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are $2n+1$ terms, the middlemost term would be the $(n+1)$th term.

For the $(n+1)$th term, you would require putting $r=n$ and not $n+1$ ($r$ varies from $0$ to $2n$ thereby giving $2n+1$ terms).

So the coefficient of the middlemost term will be $\binom{2n}{n}x^n$.